# NSTableView headerView similar to Tweetbot for Mac

Tags: macos, nstableview, nstablecellview

I'm trying to figure out a way to load two NSTableCellView's in one NSTableView. Basically, I'm trying to replicate UITableView's functionality of loading sections with different UITableView cells.

Two of my ideas were;
1. Two seperate NStableViewCells
2. An NSView in an NScrollView above an NStableView

A better example of what im trying to do is what Tweetbot for Mac's profile view does. You can see what im talking about here. http://cl.ly/QkC1

What I think they are doing is placing a tableView inside of a scrollView and doing something like that to create an UITableView like header with an NSTableView. Does anyone have any ideas on how to accomplish something like that? I've tried placing an NSView inside of an NSTableView's enclosing scrollVIew, but thats not possible from my research and what I have tried. Am I going about this the wrong way? Any ideas or examples would greatly be appreciated!